# Fetching transaction ID that created account

Tags: anchor, solana-program, account, transaction

**Background:**

In my application I am creating an account to store some arbitrary information.

I then want to display the **transaction id/address** of the transaction that created such an account.

**Question:**

Does anyone know how to do this without storing the transaction id immediately after executing the transaction?

**Options:**

One option is to look up the account address and then fetch the very first transaction id (since this created the account, right?).
If this is the only solution, does anyone know how to go about this in terms of the Solana Javascript SDK?

Are there other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
    let before: string;
    while (true) {
      const signatures = await this.connection.getSignaturesForAddress(
        new PublicKey(address),
        {
          300, // limit
          undefined, // until
          before,
        },
      );
      if (signatures.length > 0)
        before = signatures[signatures.length - 1].signature;
      if (signatures.length < limit) {
        console.log("Genesis transaction hash:", before);
        break;
      }
    }
```